# Firebase realtime database runTransaction causes database entry deletion to be detected locally

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

Edit: I overhauled the whole question upon finding the error in case this helps somebody.

I kept getting what I thought was random behavior from transactions on firebase.

When updating a counter on a database entry the following way:

```
runTransaction(ref(database, "myData/" + itemKey), (myItem) => {
    if (myItem) {
      myItem.updateByCounter ++;
      if (myItem.updateByCounter % 100 === 0) {
        myItem.updatedDate = new Date().toISOString();
      }
    }
    return myItem;
  });
```

This returned null 25 times and failed despite “myItem” existing on the database. (I've tried with and without the second conditional.)

Even worse:

```
runTransaction(
    ref(database, "myData/" + itemKey + "/updateByCounter"),
    (updateByCounter) => {
      if (updateByCounter) {
        updateByCounter++;
      }
      return updateByCounter;
    }
  );
```

Worked perfectly, but was useless to me, since I couldn’t access the rest of the item (myItem on the previous example)
Database rules were set to true (read and write), since I’m still testing, so that can’t be the problem.

I managed to pinpoint the error, but I’m not sure if it's a bug with firebase transactions behavior or if it's the intended way for them to work and I’m misusing them.

Basically, the error didn’t come from the transaction itself, but from another part of the code where I had:

```
onChildRemoved(
    ref(database, "myData/" + itemKey + "/otherChildOfTheEntry"),
    () => {
      // Item got deleted. Deal with deletion.
      // …
      return;
    }
  );
```

It seems that using transactions on the complete entity (“myItem” on the original example), causes the entry to be locally detected as removed when first returned as null and fires the onChildRemoved event, even though the entity is not being removed and the child “otherChildOfTheEntry” is not being removed or modified.

I fixed this by modifying the original transaction to:

```
    runTransaction(ref(database, "myData/" + itemKey), (myItem) => {
  if (myItem) {
    myItem.updateByCounter++;
    if (myItem.updateByCounter % 100 === 0) {
      myItem.updatedDate = new Date().toISOString();
    }
  } else {
    myItem = { otherChildOfTheEntry };
  }
  return myItem;
});
```

So that “otherChildOfTheEntry” is never null, and detecting deletion like this:

```
    onValue(
  ref(database, "myData/" + itemKey + "/otherChildOfTheEntry"),
  (deletionSnapshot) => {
    const data = deletionSnapshot.exists();
    if (!data) {
      // Item got deleted
    }

    return;
  }
);
```